# How to prove P(v|θ')=∫P(v|θ,θ') P(θ|θ')dθ

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

Given in textbook Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning by David Barber in chapter 9.2
\begin{equation}
P(v|θ')=∫P(v|θ,θ') P(θ|θ')dθ 
\end{equation}

Context: Given parameterised distribution, $P(v|θ')$

want to learn optimal parameters $θ$  given some data

specify a parameterised prior $P(θ|θ')$ with hyperparameter $θ'$ since we may have some idea of $θ$ that is appropriate.

Learning is then finding optimal $θ'$ that maximises likelihood $$P(v|θ')=∫P(v|θ,θ') P(θ|θ')dθ $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use marginalization and definition of conditional probability together:
$$\begin{align}p(v|\theta')&=\int p(v,\theta|\theta')d\theta=\int p(v|\theta,\theta')p(\theta|\theta')d\theta\end{align}$$

While thinking, consider omitting $\theta'$ from all the equations. You'll notice the conventional formulas for joint probability, marginal distribution and conditional probability.

Comment: Thanks for answering! There is also this form given in the textbook P(v|θ′)=∫P(v|θ)P(θ|θ′)dθ which has omitted the conditioning on θ′ of the first probability in the integral. Would you have any ideas how that is allowed?

Comment: Yes, that’s not true in general but very common in Bayesian analysis (e.g. hierarchical probabilistic models). Typically, the assumption is given $\theta$ we don’t need $\theta’$ to characterize $v$ because all we need is $\theta$.